# Calling a method from an injected service in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, tdd, httpbackend

I'm attempted to unit test a service. I've injected the service however the method call **getAllProducts()** doesn't appear to run however the test still passes!

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PxwPmmNQqt7BSVXx1yHI?p=preview)

service.js

```
angular.module('vsApp')
  .factory('productsDataService', function($http) {

    var service = {

      getAllProducts: getAllProducts

    };

    // get all products

    function getAllProducts() {

      return $http.get('/apiv1/getAllProducts/').then(function(data) {

        return (data);

      });

    }

    return service;
  });
```

spec.js

```
// jasmine

describe('products data service', function () {

    var $httpBackend, productsDataService;

    beforeEach(module('vsApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _productsDataService_) {

        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        productsDataService = _productsDataService_;

    }));

    it('should get all products', inject(function() {
        console.info("get all");
        // mock response for the http call in the service

        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/apiv1/getAllProducts/')
            .respond({name: 'item', price: '932'});

        //this doesn't seem to run??
        productsDataService.getAllProducts().then(function(response) {
            expect(response.data.length).toBeGreaterThan(1);

        });

    }));

});
```

Comment: "this doesn't seem to run" explain why you think it is not running ? (error ? test excuted ? )

Comment: @MoncefHassein-bey  The test passes and there is no error, however if I change the matcher to 'toBeGreaterThan(99)' it still passes

Comment: In your plunker the productsDataService is not defined, maybe it's not also in your real tests ? do a "debugger; " before the expectation to see if it is there

Comment: @MoncefHassein-bey Seems ok http://i.imgur.com/2jOO086.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have to make it sync. (all pending request will get resolved) using [$http.flush()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend);

[Working demo as expected](http://plnkr.co/edit/g7n4k0H6haHaY9xeOd5c?p=preview)

```
productsDataService.getAllProducts().then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    expect(response.data.length).toBeGreaterThan(999);

});

$httpBackend.flush(); // <=============== here.
```

Comment: My hero! Can't believe I missed that. Thank you.